# How do I set the query timeout using gremlin query for aws neptune?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I tried to use something like `g.with_('evaluationTimeout', 1)` but it does not seem to work

Comment: "it does not seem to work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening?

Comment: Which Gremlin client driver are you using and what is the version number?

Comment: @Marcin I execute the command but I don't get a timeout as I expect and just the result. Could be that the query is taking less than 1 ms? I put 1ms in the timeout

Comment: @KelvinLawrence latest one

Comment: Perhaps try a more complicated query just to make sure. Are you using the Python client or the Gremlin Console or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using one of the Gremlin GLV clients, then a query such as this one (Python in this case) will apply the per query timeout. Note that the longer form `scriptEvaluationTimeout` was deprecated in favor of the shorter form `evaluationTimeout`

```java
g.with_('scriptEvaluationTimeout',5).V().count().next()
```

or

```java
g.with_('evaluationTimeout',5).V().count().next()
```

If the query times out, you will get an exception that includes as message such as:

```java
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: 
{"detailedMessage":"A timeout occurred within the script during evaluation.","code":"TimeLimitExceededException","requestId":"9ec1e462-f47f-4876-8157-c0bf3c06ec6b"}
```

Comment: is there any difference between `with` and `with_`?

Comment: The `with_` is because I used Python for testing and `with` is a reserved word in Python so the Gremlin client uses `with_` instead.